# Customize rails generate scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I have a problem, before the command "rails generate scaffold test name: string" generated controllers like this:

```
class Teste < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_teste, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy

  # GET /testes
  # GET /testes.json
  def index
    @testes = Teste.all
  end

  # GET /testes/1
  # GET /testes/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /testes/new
  def new
    @teste = Teste.new
  end

  # GET /testes/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /testes
  # POST /testes.json
  def create
    @teste = Teste.new(teste_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @teste.save
        format.html { redirect_to testes_path, notice: 'Teste cadastrado.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @teste }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @teste.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /testes/1
  # PATCH/PUT /testes/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @teste.update(teste_params)
        format.html { redirect_to testes_path, notice: 'Teste atualizado.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @teste }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @teste.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /testes/1
  # DELETE /testes/1.json
  def destroy
    @teste.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to testes_url, notice: 'Teste excluído.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

Do not know why, but this is now generating another format

```
class TestesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_teste, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @testes = Teste.all
    respond_with(@testes)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@teste)
  end

  def new
    @teste = Teste.new
    respond_with(@teste)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @teste = Teste.new(teste_params)
    @teste.save
    respond_with(@teste)
  end

  def update
    @teste.update(teste_params)
    respond_with(@teste)
  end
```

What can it be? Why has this changed?

I would return in the previous format because my whole system is in the first format

Comment: You've upgraded Rails. Modern Rails uses `respond_with` instead of `respond_to do...`. Honestly you should probably not rely so much on scaffold generation, it's something you'll outgrow very quickly.

Comment: Scaffolding is a great way to get started, but as meagar has pointed out, it's very easy to outgrow scaffolding.

Comment: I have this problem too. How can I get back to the previous format?

Comment: I didnt do anything to my app and their gems, how could it comes out with a new scaffolding format? I tried create a new app, try a scaffold generate and it use the old format which have respond_to do ....

Answer (score 2):

The reason of this behavior is probably some gem.

I had same problem because latest version of Devise which is now shipped with Responders gem.

If this is your case too then quick fix is add following line to `aplication.rb` file:

`config.app_generators.scaffold_controller :scaffold_controller`

More info here:

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17290

https://github.com/plataformatec/responders/issues/94